# lcm of orders of reduced residue classes of $1001$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

By Euler's theorem, I know that all orders of reduced residue classes of $1001$ must divide $\phi(1001) = 720$. However, by a computer program, I know that the lcm of the orders of all $720$ reduced residue classes is $60$ (and, therefore, $1001$ has no primitive roots).

I was wondering if there was a way to see why $60$ is in fact the smallest number which all reduced residue orders must divide. Is there a way, without computing everything explicitly, I could have determined this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $1001=7\cdot 11\cdot 13$. Since $7$, $11$, and $13$ are primes, there are objects of order respectively $6$, $10$, and $12$ modulo $7$, $11$, and $13$. Thus by the Chinese Remainder Theorem there is an element of order (modulo $1001$) equal to the lcm of $6$, $10$, and $12$, which is $60$.

It is easy to show that there is no element of order greater than $60$. If $a$ is relatively prime to $1001$, then by Fermat's Theorem we have $a^6\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, and therefore $a^{60}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$. Similarly, $a^{60}\equiv 1$ modulo $11$ and $13$, so $a^{60}\equiv 1\pmod{1001}$.

For the general result along these lines, please search under the [Carmichael $\lambda$-function,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) or *least universal exponent*.

Comment: This answer suggests that the computer program is wrong. I will double check.

Comment: @shuckles No it's fine, as lcm(6, 10, 12)=60

Comment: Oops, right. Although we know there is an element of order $60$, why can't there be any elements of greater order?

Comment: For the general result, google the Carmichael $\lambda$-function.

Comment: That is the easier part. If $a$ is relatively prime to $1001$, then by little Fermat we have $a^6\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, and therefore $a^{60}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$. Similarly, $a^{60}\equiv 1$ modulo $11$ and $13$, so $a^{60}\equiv 1\pmod{1001}$.